# Is garbage created in this foreach loop?

Tags: c#, list, garbage-collection, foreach, memory-management

I came across a method to change a list in a `foreach` loop by converting to a list in itself like this:

```
foreach (var item in myList.ToList())
{
     //add or remove items from myList
}
```

(If you attempt to modify `myList` directly an error is thrown since the enumerator basically locks it)

This works because it's not the original `myList` that's being modified. My question is, does this method create `garbage` when the loop is over (namely from the `List` that's returned from the `ToList` method? For small loops, would it be preferable to using a `for loop` to avoid the creation of garbage?

Comment: Isn't the reasoning backwards, at least given the comment "// add or remove items from **myList**"? Shouldn't it read (longish): "This works because it is not `myList` that is **iterated** (but rather a copy created using `ToList()`), so `myList` can be modified in the foreach-loop."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second list is going to be garbage, there will be garbage for an enumerator that is used in *building* the second list, and add in the enumerator that the `foreach` would spawn, which you would have had with or without the second list.

Should you switch to a `for`? Maybe, *if* you can point to this region of code being a true performance bottleneck. Otherwise, code for simplicity and maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  `ToList()` would create another list that would need to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting technique which I will keep in mind for the future! (I can't believe I've never thought of that!)

Anyway, yes, the list that you are building doesn't magically unallocate itself. The possible performance problems with this technique are:

1. Increased memory usage (building a `List`, separate from the `IEnumerable`). Probably not that big of a deal, unless you do this very frequently, or the `IEnumerable` is very large.
2. Decreased speed, since it has to go through the `IEnumerable` at once to build the `List`.
3. Also, if enumerating the `IEnumerable` has side effects, they will all be triggered by this process.

Unless this is actually inside an inner loop, or you're working with very large data sets, you can probably do this without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `ToList()` method creates "garbage".  I would just indexing.

```
for (int i = MyList.Count - 1; 0 <= i; --i)
{
    var item = MyList[i];
    //add or remove items from myList
}
```

Comment: I would hold off on making this optimization until it was shown that the original code was a bottle neck. If it isn't, there is no point in making the code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

It's non-deterministic. But the reference created from the call `ToList()` will be GCd eventually.

I wouldn't worry about it too much, since all it would be holding at most would be references or small value types.